# Populate API data on action button shows in Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiimage

I am working on App in which images comes from the server. Now in that image some of the points will be already there on which on i have to make a click action & show information of that particular touch.

Here is sample Image:

[image]

Now here in above image you can see the points. that is a part of image. I need to put action over there if click on that area than show the information of that particular area from API.

Can anyone suggest me the way of it & also any alternative solution if this one is not possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your API also tells you a co-ordinate for those points that are highlighted in the image, then...

1. Calculate a `CGRect` based on the point, either as a fixed size if they are all the same, or based on the text the API would have to supply you.
2. Add a `UIButton` as a subview to the view holding the `UIImageView`, make this button a `CustomType`, with no text or background image.
3. Add a `tag` to the `UIButton` so that you can uniquely identify an clicks
4. Add targets for the buttons, in the IBAction, use the tag from the `UIButton` to work out the element you are interested in and process accordingly.

If you're API isn't given you positions of the points, then I would suggest the API needs improving

Comment: API is under development so positions will be there in API response

Comment: Can they not also give you the size of the rectangle they've used to draw on the labels? Might save you a lot of hassle

Comment: Sure thanks for the useful information i'll let him know

Comment: another twist comes there is they'll provide 2 images from server. 1 with this this labels & 1 without labels. does that help or make any sense ?

Comment: only if you want to show image without labels - think you need to ask them really

Comment: So basically if clickable points required than the only option is to get the coordinates